# Save site's source code to vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, curl, vector

I'm trying to save site's source code to vector, where every line of source code is a new vector element, because I only need to use one specific line (number 47) in my program. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why store the whole thing if you already know the line number you need.

Comment: @RedSerpent is there a way to save only one line in a string?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am not really familiar with curl, don't have an idea what to look for

Comment: @AdamMichalski not that I know of, you can use hansmaad's solution and instead of storing each line in the vector, if you are 100% sure that the data you want is on line 47, just do a counter til you reach that line and store it in a string object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the data from the URL. 
Using cURL:

```
std::vector<char> LoadFromUrl(const std::string& url)
{
    struct Content
    {
        std::vector<char> data;

        static size_t Write(char * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * p)
        {
            return static_cast<Content*>(p)->WriteImpl(data, size, nmemb);
        }

        size_t WriteImpl(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
        {
            data.insert(end(data), ptr, ptr + size * nmemb);
            return size * nmemb;
        }
    };

    Content content;

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &Content::Write);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    content.data.push_back('\0');

    return content.data;
}
```

Tokenize the data using strtok or boost tokenizer or your own implementation:

```
std::vector<std::string> LoadLines(const std::string& url)
{
    std::vector<char> content = LoadFromUrl(url);

    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    for(char* token = strtok(&content.front(), "\n");
        token; token = strtok(0, "\n"))
    {
        lines.push_back(std::string(token));
    }
    return lines;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> lines = LoadLines(
        "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773009/save-sites-source-code-to-vectorstring");

    std::copy(begin(lines), end(lines), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```